# Running Liberty server as embedded from maven using maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, embedding, websphere-liberty

IBM Liberty documentation claims that it is possible to start/stop/manage Liberty server using SPI directly from the code. I'd like to use such functionality to create integration tests for my REST services.

Reference on original article:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_extend_embed.html?lang=en

I want to create integration test that:

1) Start Liberty server with my own 'server.xml'. I want to provide specific DataSource and security here.

2) Deploy an EAR application on Liberty server.

3) Run REST-Assured tests on Liberty server.

4) Undeploy application and shutdown Liberty server.

Basically I stuck on 1st stage - I can't start server because I am getting 'NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.EmbeddedServerImpl' exception. The link above describes that 'ws-server.jar' from Liberty installation must be used, but what about referencing it from maven dependencies? I suppose that I could specify some artifact from IBM maven repo 'https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/' and use it to start Liberty as embedded server directly from my unit tests, but I can't find what that artifact should be.

So, to rephrase myself: what would be maven artifact in IBM's repository that contains EmbeddedServerImpl class? And is it enough to include that artifact or there are more of them required for liberty embedding?

Comment: Consider using the [Liberty Maven plugin](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven) to run your integration tests. In fact, a sample project generated using the [liberty plugin archetype](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven#liberty-plugin-archetype) shows just that.

Comment: For the NoClassDefFoundError, any other information on the setup? The specific Liberty version and execution environment may help. Was the ws-server.jar moved from wlp/bin/tools?

Comment: @jgawor, lets say I have multiple integration tests, and I want run each of them on the clean server (fresh database for example). Starting Liberty only once in 'pre-integration-test' phase will keep the same database for all tests and they might affect each other.

Comment: @jgawor, That is why I want to control liberty start-up manually. Actually, having an API similar to liberty plugin goals I could control liberty server and run each integration test on a newly started liberty instance. Just by using \@Before and \@After (in JUnit case).

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference it from the Maven repository because it must be part of the Liberty installation that you want to start as it uses it's location to work out what it is starting.

I wrote an article and sample a little while ago outlining different techniques for writing functional/integration tests against Liberty including using a JUnit Rule with the Embedded Server starting and stopping the server:

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/writing-functional-tests-liberty/

https://github.com/WASdev/sample.functionaltest

This was using Gradle to do the build script part so I included the launch JAR with:

```
fvtRuleCompile fileTree(dir: "${libertyRoot}/bin/tools", include: 'ws-server.jar')
```

The same can be achieved in a Maven build environment by using a System Dependency:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `ws-server.jar` is provided in the IBM Maven DHE repository, only Liberty API's and SPI's and some packaged runtimes are provided to the user as Maven dependencies.

By the way, if you're using artifacts from the IBM Maven DHE repository, you may want to change them for the ones that are now provided in Maven Central, see:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver